# Data not written to csv file after script is run

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am new to python and having some trouble outputting my data into a csv file. the script runs but the file is blank that is created with no data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import smtplib
import csv

os.system('clear')

class CreateList(object):
    def add_items(self):
        shop_list = []
        print("Lets create a shopping list for you..\n")
        print("Please enter DONE when you have all the items needed for your shopping list.")
        while True:
            add_item = input("> ")
            if add_item == 'DONE':
                break
                shop_list.append(add_item)
                print("Here is your current shopping list:")
        csv = open('shoplist.csv', 'w')
        for item in shop_list:
            print(item)
            csv.write(item + '\n')
        csv.close()

c = CreateList()
c.add_items()
```

Comment: usually CSV files are comma seperated you're simply adding them one entry each line. I also might suggest you're using `with open(file,'w') as f:`  for your file operations.

Comment: I also want to emphasize staying away from manually openin and closing csv files, research the `with open` syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may just have some extra indentation. Here's the same script but some indentation has been removed on lines 19 and 20.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import smtplib
import csv

os.system('clear')

class CreateList(object):
    def add_items(self):
        shop_list = []
        print("Lets create a shopping list for you..\n")
        print("Please enter DONE when you have all the items needed for your shopping list.")
        while True:
            add_item = input("> ")
            if add_item == 'DONE':
                break
            shop_list.append(add_item)
        print("Here is your current shopping list:")
        csv = open('shoplist.csv', 'w')
        for item in shop_list:
            print(item)
            csv.write(item + '\n')
        csv.close()

c = CreateList()
c.add_items()
```

Comment: I use Visual code studio is there like a plugin that can detect the space issues and fix them for you? I run into this issue all the time

Comment: Of course! Pretty much any IDE has that. I use Spyder, give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

There's an `else` missing. Your `input` is not appending anything to `shop_list` and thus nothing gets written to the file.

```
import os
import smtplib
import csv

os.system('clear')

class CreateList(object):
    def add_items(self):
        shop_list = []
        print("Lets create a shopping list for you..\n")
        print("Please enter DONE when you have all the items needed for your shopping list.")
        while True:
            add_item = input("> ")
            if add_item == 'DONE':
                break
            else: # <<< missing
                shop_list.append(add_item)
                print("Here is your current shopping list:")
        csv = open('shoplist.csv', 'w')
        for item in shop_list:
            print(item)
            csv.write(item + '\n')
        csv.close()

c = CreateList()
c.add_items()
```